# How can I get PHPUnit MockObjects to return different values based on a parameter?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I've got a PHPUnit mock object that returns `'return value'` no matter what its arguments:

```
// From inside a test...
$mock = $this->getMock('myObject', 'methodToMock');
$mock->expects($this->any))
     ->method('methodToMock')
     ->will($this->returnValue('return value'));
```

What I want to be able to do is return a different value based on the arguments passed to the mock method. I've tried something like:

```
$mock = $this->getMock('myObject', 'methodToMock');

// methodToMock('one')
$mock->expects($this->any))
     ->method('methodToMock')
     ->with($this->equalTo('one'))
     ->will($this->returnValue('method called with argument "one"'));

// methodToMock('two')
$mock->expects($this->any))
     ->method('methodToMock')
     ->with($this->equalTo('two'))
     ->will($this->returnValue('method called with argument "two"'));
```

But this causes PHPUnit to complain if the mock isn't called with the argument `'two'`, so I assume that the definition of `methodToMock('two')` overwrites the definition of the first.

So my question is: Is there any way to get a PHPUnit mock object to return a different value based on its arguments? And if so, how?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Use a callback.  e.g. (straight from PHPUnit documentation):

```
<?php
class StubTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testReturnCallbackStub()
    {
        $stub = $this->getMock(
          'SomeClass', array('doSomething')
        );

        $stub->expects($this->any())
             ->method('doSomething')
             ->will($this->returnCallback('callback'));

        // $stub->doSomething() returns callback(...)
    }
}

function callback() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    // ...
}
?>
```

Do whatever processing you want in the callback() and return the result based on your $args as appropriate.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation?  I can't seem to find it with "the Google"

Comment: Note that you can use a method as a callback by passing an array, e.g. `$this->returnCallback(array('MyClassTest','myCallback'))`.

Comment: It should also be possible to pass directly a closure to it

Comment: This should be used only in rare cases. I would suggest using [returnValueMap](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/test-doubles.html) instead as it does not require custom logic to be written in the callback.

Comment: function callback has same name as \PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::callback

Comment: I can't thank you enough. Also, with PHP versions > 5.4, you can use an anonymous function as the callback. `$this->returnCallback(function() { // ... })`

Comment: This answer is being deprecated. `->will($this->returnCallback(...))` should be replaced with `->willReturnCallback(...)`

Answer (score 135):

From the latest phpUnit docs: "Sometimes a stubbed method should return different values depending on a predefined list of arguments. You can use [returnValueMap()](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest5.php) to create a map that associates arguments with corresponding return values."

```
$mock->expects($this->any())
    ->method('getConfigValue')
    ->will(
        $this->returnValueMap(
            array(
                array('firstparam', 'secondparam', 'retval'),
                array('modes', 'foo', array('Array', 'of', 'modes'))
            )
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 54):

I had a similar problem (although slightly different... I didn't need different return value based on arguments, but had to test to ensure 2 sets of arguments were being passed to the same function). I stumbled upon using something like this:

```
$mock = $this->getMock();
$mock->expects($this->at(0))
    ->method('foo')
    ->with(...)
    ->will($this->returnValue(...));

$mock->expects($this->at(1))
    ->method('foo')
    ->with(...)
    ->will($this->returnValue(...));
```

It's not perfect, since it requires that the order of the 2 calls to foo() is known, but in practice this probably isn't *too* bad.

Comment: The at() matcher has been deprecated. It will be removed in PHPUnit 10. Please refactor your test to not rely on the order in which methods are invoked.

Answer (score 30):

You would probably want to do a callback in a OOP fashion:

```
<?php
class StubTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testReturnAction()
    {
        $object = $this->getMock('class_name', array('method_to_mock'));
        $object->expects($this->any())
            ->method('method_to_mock')
            ->will($this->returnCallback(array($this, 'returnTestDataCallback')));

        $object->returnAction('param1');
        // assert what param1 should return here

        $object->returnAction('param2');
        // assert what param2 should return here
    }
    
    public function returnTestDataCallback()
    {
        $args = func_get_args();

        // process $args[0] here and return the data you want to mock
        return 'The parameter was ' . $args[0];
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 25):

It is not exactly what you ask, but in some cases it can help:

```
$mock->expects( $this->any() ) )
 ->method( 'methodToMock' )
 ->will( $this->onConsecutiveCalls( 'one', 'two' ) );
```

[onConsecutiveCalls](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest7.php) - returns a list of values in the specified order

Answer (score 13):

Pass two level array, where each element is an array of:

- first are method parameters, and last is return value.

example:

```
->willReturnMap([
    ['firstArg', 'secondArg', 'returnValue']
])
```

Comment: the best answer!
note: params with default values should also be specified

Answer (score 5):

You also can return the argument as follows:

```
$stub = $this->getMock(
  'SomeClass', array('doSomething')
);

$stub->expects($this->any())
     ->method('doSomething')
     ->will($this->returnArgument(0));
```

As you can see in the [Mocking documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html), the method `returnValue($index)` allows to return the given argument.

Comment: I think Stub vs Mock is already confusing topic for many people. You make it even more confusing by doing `$stub = $this->getMock(`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
public function TestSomeCondition($condition){
  $mockObj = $this->getMockObject();
  $mockObj->setReturnValue('yourMethod',$condition);
}
```

Comment: I think that's SimpleTest code, not PHPUnit. But no, it isn't what I want to achieve.

Say I had a mock object that returned a word for a given number. My mock method would need to return "one" when called with 1, "two" when called with 2 etc.
$

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which I couldn't work out as well (there's surprisingly little information about for PHPUnit). In my case, I just made each test separate test - known input and known output. I realised that I didn't need to make a jack-of-all-trades mock object, I only needed a specific one for a specific test, and thus I separated the tests out and can test individual aspects of my code as a separate unit. I'm not sure if this might be applicable to you or not, but that's down to what you need to test.

Comment: Unfortunately that wouldn't work in my situation. The mock is being passed into a method I'm testing, and the test method calls the mocked method with different arguments. 

It's interesting to know that you couldn't solve the problem though. It sounds like this could be a PHPUnit limitation.

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->BusinessMock = $this->createMock('AppBundle\Entity\Business');

    public function testBusiness()
    {
        /*
            onConcecutiveCalls : Whether you want that the Stub returns differents values when it will be called .
        */
        $this->BusinessMock ->method('getEmployees')
                                ->will($this->onConsecutiveCalls(
                                            $this->returnArgument(0),
                                            $this->returnValue('employee')                                      
                                            )
                                      );
        // first call

        $this->assertInstanceOf( //$this->returnArgument(0),
                'argument',
                $this->BusinessMock->getEmployees()
                );
       // second call


        $this->assertEquals('employee',$this->BusinessMock->getEmployees()) 
      //$this->returnValue('employee'),


    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try :

```
->with($this->equalTo('one'),$this->equalTo('two))->will($this->returnValue('return value'));
```

Comment: This answer does not apply to the original question, but it details a similar problem I had: verify that a certain _set_ of parameters is provided. PHPUnit's with() accepts multiple arguments, one matcher for each parameter.