# PHPUnit - creating Mock objects to act as stubs for properties

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I'm trying to configure a Mock object in PHPunit to return values for different properties (that are accessed using the __get function)

Example:

```
class OriginalObject {
 public function __get($name){
switch($name)
 case "ParameterA":
  return "ValueA";
 case "ParameterB":
  return "ValueB";
 }
}
```

I'm trying to mock this using:

```
$mockObject = $this->getMock("OrigionalObject");

$mockObject    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('__get')
    ->with($this->equalTo('ParameterA'))
    ->will($this->returnValue("ValueA"));

$mockObject    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('__get')
    ->with($this->equalTo('ParameterB'))
    ->will($this->returnValue("ValueB"));
```

but this fails horribly :-(

Comment: Are the typos ("Origional" instead of "Original", missing closing quotes at ValueA and ValueB) in the mock code part of your actual code, or transcription errors?

Comment: LOL thanks Phil (for pointing out my dyslexia) 
The typos (amended now) are just in the example code - clearly this isn't the actual code being executed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't tried mocking __get yet, but maybe this will work:

```
// getMock() is deprecated
// $mockObject = $this->getMock("OrigionalObject");
$mockObject = $this->createMock("OrigionalObject");

$mockObject->expects($this->at(0))
    ->method('__get')
    ->with($this->equalTo('ParameterA'))
    ->will($this->returnValue('ValueA'));

$mockObject->expects($this->at(1))
    ->method('__get')
    ->with($this->equalTo('ParameterB'))
    ->will($this->returnValue('ValueB'));
```

I've already used $this->at() in a test and it works (but isn't an optimal solution). I got it from this tread:

[How can I get PHPUnit MockObjects to return different values based on a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277914/how-can-i-get-phpunit-mockobjects-to-return-differernt-values-based-on-a-paramete)

Comment: hey koen
$this->at() works for me - Thank you ;-)
Why don't you think that this is an optimal solution?

Comment: It's not really scalable and the test is difficult to read. A callback may be easier to read if you give it a good name. But in the first place I would look at trying to refactor the __get.

Comment: also, you are testing state (which some regard as bad practice) and even more, private state (which many regard as a bad practice). Of course there are smart folks who don't see a problem in that and you may be one of them.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
class Test extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
...
    function testSomething() {
         $mockObject = $this->getMock("OrigionalObject");

         $mockObject
              ->expects( $this->any() )
              ->method('__get')
              ->will( $this->returnCallback('myMockGetter'));
         ...
     }
...
}

function myMockGetter( $classPropertyName ) {
    switch( $classPropertyName ) {
        case 'ParameterA':
            return 'ValueA';

        case 'ParameterB':
            return 'ValueB';
    }
}
... ...
```

Comment: I think my solution is more optimal than koen, but he makes some important points in his comments. I think one possible solution would be to create a test class, and not use a mock object. This is often used for things like HTTP adapters.