# How to mock subclass of Doctrine_Record class and stub its properties?

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony1, doctrine, phpunit

I have a doctrine class User which is of this hierarchy Doctrine_Record -> BaseUser -> User. In PHP symfony you are aware that you can access doctrine record using array accessor as well methods. Each class has @property and a method.

```
$user['mode'] == $user->getMode()
```

When I am writing PHPUnit test cases, I am unable to mock occurrences where array accessor method is used.

Here is sample code from unit test as well the actual code -

User.php

```
class User extends BaseUser {
public function clearInactiveUsers()
  {
    foreach ($this->users as $user) {
      if (!$user['mode']) {
        unset($this->users[array_search($user, $this->users)]);
        $user->delete();
      }
    }
    unset($user);
  }
}
```

This is the test for it

UserTest.php

```
public function testOnlyInactiveUsersAreRemoved()
  {
    $userGroup = new UserGroup();
    $user_1 = $this->getMock('User');
    $user_2 = $this->getMock('User');
    $user_1->expects($this->at(0))->method('__get')->with($this->equalTo('mode'))->will($this->returnValue(1));
    $user_2->expects($this->at(0))->method('__get')->with($this->equalTo('mode'))->will($this->returnValue(0));
    $userGroup->adduser($user_1);
    $userGroup->adduser($user_2);
    $userGroup->clearInactiveUsers();
    $this->assertCount(1, $userGroup->getUsers());
  }
```

I am trying to mock the occurrence `$user['mode']` in the code. What I am doing wrong?

I have referenced following link and wrote above code.

[PHPUnit - creating Mock objects to act as stubs for properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304633/phpunit-creating-mock-objects-to-act-as-stubs-for-properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell PHPUnit to mock the methods before setting their expectations. Also, you're accessing `mode` via array access--not property access. Does `BaseUser` implement [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php)? You should be mocking `offsetGet` instead of `__get`.

```
$user_1 = $this->getMock('User', array('offsetGet'));
$user_2 = $this->getMock('User', array('offsetGet'));
$user_1->expects($this->at(0))->method('offsetGet')->with($this->equalTo('mode'))->will($this->returnValue(1));
$user_2->expects($this->at(0))->method('offsetGet')->with($this->equalTo('mode'))->will($this->returnValue(0));
```

Comment: I just edited my code. The User class code is pasted above as well.