# How to mock object properties?

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, mocking, phpunit

I'm trying to mock properties but can't get it to work. In this case I'm trying to mock request property `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304633/phpunit-creating-mock-objects-to-act-as-stubs-for-properties) answer I should return a value for `__get`

Following code keeps showing `NULL`:

```
$testRequest = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request')
  ->disableOriginalConstructor()
  ->getMock();
$testRequest->expects($this->any())
  ->method('__get')
  ->with($this->equalTo('request'))
  ->will($this->returnValue("working"));
var_dump($testRequest->request);
```

Maybe it's because the answer is too old so checking out the [current documentation](http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/test-doubles.html) of mocking but that one doesn't mention how to mock properties at all.

According to another answer I can try the following:

```
private $post=array('search'=>'abc','start'=>null);
...
$paramBag = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag')
  ->disableOriginalConstructor()
  ->getMock();
foreach($this->post as $key=>$value){
  echo "setting:".$key.' with:'.$value.PHP_EOL;              
  $paramBag->expects($this->any())
    ->method('get')
    ->with($this->equalTo($key))
    ->will($this->returnValue($value));
}
$this->request = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request')
  ->disableOriginalConstructor()
  ->getMock();
$this->request->request=$paramBag;
echo ($this->request->request->get('start'));
```

That gives me:

```
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:get> when invoked zero or more times
Parameter 0 for invocation Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::get('search', null, false) does not match expected value.
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'search'
+'start'
```

Is it not possible to override multiple methods with different values? Again, the documentation completely lacks any examples of that.

If I try `echo ($this->request->request->get('start'));` it will fail on expecting search but getting start. There is no way I can give it something that doesn't fail.

Trying to unit test but Symfony2 does not seem to have such a thing. Every [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html) almost immediately skips unit testing with examples of ordinary classes needing no dependencies and then moves to functional testing. And some documentation flat out say [unit testing for repositories is not recommended](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/doctrine.html).

I would like to see if DQL statements are created correctly though and am left with no documented option to unit test this.

Can do this part by creating a fake `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository` class and include that file at the start of my test. Tried the same with `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` but get a `can't re define this class` when trying to do that. Somehow when my test is loaded `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` already is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure how you mean mock properties, I would assume properties are set via getters and setters and then you could just set them with whatever Mock you want.

If however you need to assign a mock object to a private /protected property for which you do not have an accessor method, you can do this:

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass($objectThatContainsThePropertyToMock);
$property   = $reflection->getProperty($propertyName);
$property->setAccessible(true);
return $property->setValue($mockedObject);
```