# Symfony2 unit testing service class using other services

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony

I'm doing some unit testing (phpunit) for a Symfony2 Bundle and i want to test this method :

```
/**
 * Set a flash notification
 * @param array $message
 */
public function setFlashNotification(array $message) {


    if (!isset($message['key'])) {
        throw new \ErrorException("Message array must contains a key");
    }

    if (!isset($message['content'])) {
        throw new \ErrorException("Message array must contains a content");
    }

    $this->container->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(self::SESSION_KEY . $message['key'], $message['content']);
}
```

In my tests it seems i need Symfony2 service container to use the session, but how can i unit test this method without Symfony2 AppKernel.php dependency ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that this method is part of a class. As a best practice, this class should not receive the whole container as a dependency, but should require only a subset of strictly required dependencies.
For example, in this case, you should inject only `session`.

Doing this lets you mock the session object and check if, for example, the method `getFlashBag` is getting called.

If you need the container in your class, I suggest you to functionally test it with `WebTestCase`.

Comment: Sound advice about injecting required services.  However he could also mock the container if needed and return a session service mock when the get method is called passing "session": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277914/how-can-i-get-phpunit-mockobjects-to-return-differernt-values-based-on-a-paramet/292423#292423