# Build a UnitTest with multiple options on the same mocked-method

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit

I have a problem to test a Method like that

```
public function index(){

    if($this->request->is('get')){

        if($this->Session->check('saveConflict')){
            $this->set('conflict',true);
        }else{
            $this->set('data','test');
        }

        if($this->Session->check('full')){
            $this->set('data',$this->Model->find('all'));
        }else{
            $this->set('data','test');
        }

    }else{
        throw new BadRequestException;

    }
}
```

unless that method maybe doesn't make sense, here is my problem. I have to call the method "check" on the Session-Component twice. But I want that for example the first methode mock-call retruns a "false" and the second a "true".

Here's what I have

```
        $this->Editors->Session
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('check')
        ->will($this->returnValue(true));
```

I've tried it with the expectation "$this->at(1)" the call via order-index. But i think that isnt pretty clever because if I add a Session->check anywhere in the interpreted way though my base-method for example i have to change all those test-lines to make it work properly again.

I use CakePHP 2.4.6 and php-unit 4.1.3.

Is there any other why to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use the

```
->will($this->onConsecutiveCalls(array('return_value1',
                                        'retur_value2',
                                        ...)));
```

Give the sequence of the return value in the order you want, the mocked method will return it in order.Or you can try the `$this->returnCallback` to do some sophisticated customize.You can find the example here [How can I get PHPUnit MockObjects to return differernt values based on a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277914/how-can-i-get-phpunit-mockobjects-to-return-differernt-values-based-on-a-paramet).

Example
If you just want to do the unit test and cover all the path,I'll do like this:

```
public function testIndex()
{
  ....
  $this->Editors->Session
    ->expects($this->any())
    ->method('check')
    ->will($this->returnCallback(array($this,'sessionCallback')));
  $this->object->index();
  $this->object->index();
  .....
}
private $sessionFlag;
public function sessionCallback($value)
{
  $rtnValue = $this->sessionFlag[$value];
  $this->sessionFlag[$value] = (!$rtnValue);
  return $rtnValue;
}
```

Comment: So if i want to add anything in my class-flow which touches those mocked method i have to change the whole tests i've done. And that means i also can use This->at() index stuff.

Comment: Would you like to show me how you use the at()?If you change the code in the index() where invoke the check()and use the onConsecutiveCalls(), I think you have to change the code.But there is no need to change the test code in other testcases.And if you implement a perfect callback to generate the return values maybe there's also no need to change the test code I think...